# How to implement pull to refresh with Android's Gallery view

Tags: android, page-refresh, galleryview

I wanna implement pull to refresh event with Android's Gallery view like IOS application name "500px" how to do this, or I should use HorizontalScrollView instead of Gallery ?

Comment: Do you mean you want horizontal pull to refresh?

Comment: Yes, I want  horizontal pull to refresh.

Comment: Are you using Customized Gallery for your application. If yes means, Try to implement the pull to refresh from [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) example

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Chris Banes [Pull-to-refresh library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) now implements *horizontal* pull-to-refresh.

**end Update**

I'm not aware of any components with horizontal pull-to-refresh available on github or anywhere googleable.

To create your own component, have a look at these pull-to-refresh components and their source code as a starting point. Just check their licenses before you implement anything:

[Pull To Refresh for Android](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) by [Johan Nilsson](https://github.com/johannilsson). The component extends ListView directly which makes the source straightforward to understand if you've worked with Android's ListView before.

[Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) by [Chris Banes](https://github.com/chrisbanes). It includes many features including pull-up-to-get-older and a double pull-up pull-down state. This is perhaps not the right starting point IMHO if you want to implement only pull-to-refresh since it's so comprehensive, but can be of interest if you want to build something really feature-rich.